# VBoxManage execute .bat on guest VM

Tags: windows, batch-file, virtualbox, remote-execution

I use
VBoxManage: Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 5.1.18,

while trying to remotely execute a .bat file from host to guest,
I tried the following command:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol <i>VMNAME</i> --username <i>USER</i> --domain <i>DOMAIN</i> --password <i>PASSWORD</i> run --exe cmd.exe -- "C:\script\script.bat"
```

but it doesn't seem to work and i get the following error:

> ```
> VBoxManage : VBoxManage.exe: error: The guest execution service is not
> ready (yet) At line:1 char:1
> + VBoxManage guestcontrol <i>VMNAME</i> --username <i>USER</i> --domain <i>DOMAIN</i> --pass...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (VBoxManage.exe:...not ready (yet):String) [], RemoteException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component
> GuestProcessWrap, interface IGuestProcess, callee IUnknown
> VBoxManage.exe: error: Context:
> "WaitForArray(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aWaitStartFlags),
> gctlRunGetRemainingTime(msStart, cMsTimeout), &waitResult)" at line
> 1529 of file  VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp
> ```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to run remotely the .bat on the guest VM?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: It looks like you are running the command in a powershell session instead of a cmd window. Powershell tries to interpret the parameters itself and not pass them to VBoxManage.exe. Either quote properly or use cmd.exe

Comment: I found another way to solve the problem, I have installed PsExec and instead of the previous command I use this <code> psexec.exe \\<SERVER_NAME> -u "<GUEST_USER>" -p "<GUEST_PASSWORD>" -i -d "C:\script\script.bat"

Comment: Is it possible to run host file from guest using PsExec?